# RSocketTcpClient is not a constructor - NodeJS with Rsocket-js

Tags: node.js, rsocket

I would like to run Rsocket TCP client on NodeJs using simple example from Rsocket guide(https://rsocket.io/guides/rsocket-js/client/rsocket-tcp-client):

```
async function createClient(options) {
  const client = new RSocketClient({
    setup: {
      dataMimeType: 'text/plain',
      keepAlive: 1000000, // avoid sending during test
      lifetime: 100000,
      metadataMimeType: 'text/plain',
    },
    transport: new RSocketTCPClient({
      host: options.host,
      port: options.port,
    }),
  });

  return await client.connect();
}

async function run() {
  const rsocket = await createClient({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 9898,
  });
}

await run();
```

but when I am trying to run app by `node app.js` there is an error:
`TypeError: RSocketTcpClient is not a constructor`.
I've checked implementation of `RSocketTcpClient`, and it looks like there is constructor:

```
export class RSocketTcpClient extends RSocketTcpConnection {
  constructor(options: net.TcpSocketConnectOpts, encoders?: Encoders<any>);
  connect(): void;
}
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong? I am using simple package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rsocket-example",
  "private": true,
  "description": "RSocket example",
  "version": "0.0.27",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js.git"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "rsocket-core": "^0.0.27",
    "rsocket-flowable": "^0.0.27",
    "rsocket-tcp-server": "^0.0.27",
    "rsocket-types": "^0.0.27",
    "rsocket-websocket-client": "^0.0.27",
    "rsocket-websocket-server": "^0.0.27"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source project, *[rsocket-js](https://rsocket.io/guides/rsocket-js/)* in here, seems to have transpiration misconfigured letting the **default export** for the `RSocketTCPClient` class declaration go under a `default` variable.

You workaround would then either to tweak the transpiler configuration in your own project or use just the `default` exported object as follows:

```
// instead of new RSocketTCPClient()
new RSocketTCPClient.default({
    host: options.host,
    port: options.port,
});
```

Comment: I am facing same issue in angular any workaround for that?